# Install/Restart Script in PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

I have a script that uses the `-Authentication` parameter of [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) and therefore requires PowerShell 7+. I'd like my script to check for PowerShell 7, install it if necessary, and restart itself in PowerShell 7 with it's current parameters to continue executing.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
# Check for required PowerShell version (7+)
if (!($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7)) {
  try {
    
    # Install PowerShell 7
    if(!(Test-Path "$env:SystemDrive\Program Files\PowerShell\7")) {
      Write-Output 'Installing PowerShell version 7...'
      Invoke-Expression "& { $(Invoke-RestMethod https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI -Quiet"
    }

    # Refresh PATH
    $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
    
    # Restart script in PowerShell 7
    pwsh "`"$PSCommandPath`"" (($MyInvocation.Line -split '\.ps1[\s\''\"]\s*', 2)[-1]).Split(' ')

  } catch {
    Write-Output 'PowerShell 7 was not installed. Update PowerShell and try again.'
    throw $Error
  } finally { Exit }
}
```

Now, **this works**, but it feels really dirty.

- Is there a cleaner/safer way to accomplish what I'm wanting?
- Is there a way to get around the lack of the `-Authentication` parameter on `Invoke-RestMethod` without needing PowerShell 7 that I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may include a check if the script runs with administrative rights. Without it wouldn't be possible to install PowerShell v7. Have you considered simply to provide the [#requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.2) statement and leave the rest to the caller of the script?

Comment: @Olaf I have made these considerations. I will be running these scripts from my RMM platform as SYSTEM, so checking for admin won't be necessary. Because I am running these scripts from my RMM, handling the PowerShell install within the script is necessary for automation.

Great recommendations though!