# How do I change which Powershell version is used in a remote session?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

I have a Powershell script which creates a session to a virtual machine. In this remote session I want the machine to read data from a json file and return a custom object from that data, hence I am using the -AsHashtable flag for the ConvertFrom-Json command to do this. However this flag was introduced in Powershell 6 and when I write the powershell version from the remote session to the output the session displays "5.1" as powershell version...

The virtual machine has Powershell 7.2.5 installed and when manually logging onto the vm and launching Powershell 7 and executing the commands it operates as expected. How do I tell the session in my script to use Powershell 7?

Comment: "the -AsHashtable flag" of which command?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen right... updated question to specify which command I use for json conversion. My bad, and thanks!

Comment: I'm not putting this in as an answer because someone may have a better way, but the first thing that comes to my mind is to have the script relaunch itself in PWSH: [Install/Restart Script in PowerShell 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71057170/4190564)

Comment: @Darin Wouldn't that close the actual remote session?

Comment: @Olaf, I think you are right.  With that in mind, for it to work you would have to call itself in PWSH, retrieve any results you need from the PWSH call, and then return those results in from the script ran in 5.1.  Which sounds like an interesting challenge.  If no answers this, and I have time later today, I may just try that.

Comment: @Olaf, it turns out I had to use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock` from within the scriptblock in order to pass itself to pwsh.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes that the [PowerShell ZIP package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2#zip) has been downloaded and unzipped to the remote computer's `C:\Users\Public\PSv7\` path.  If PowerShell 7 is installed with an installer on the remote computer, then `C:\Users\Public\PSv7\pwsh.exe` can probably be reduced to `pwsh`.  The `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` is probably not needed, but I would recommend keeping `-NoProfile` for performance.

```
$ComputerName = 'RemotePCName'
$Temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 7) {
        return (C:\Users\Public\PSv7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock)
    }
    else {
        return "[$($Env:ComputerName)] {$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)}"
    }
}
Write-Host "$Temp"
```

The code:

1. Runs a ScriptBlock on the remote system, saving result to $Temp.
2. In ScriptBlock: If the current PowerShell version is less than 7, then call pwsh passing self's ScriptBlock.
3. In ScriptBlock: In `Else` block, return the current machine's name and PowerShell version as a string.
4. After exit of ScriptBlock, Write $Temp to Host, showing the machine name and PowerShell version where the `else` part of the script was ran.

Commands, such as `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable`, should run fine inside the `else` statement.

This is the first time I tried passing a ScriptBlock to pwsh.exe from within PowerShell, so, it appears to work, but I'm not sure how pwsh.exe is receiving the ScriptBlock or returning info on exit.  I wouldn't be surprised if only `[string]` values can be returned from pwsh.exe.

**Basic Parameter Version:**

This version flips the `if` statement so the `else` part is where `pwsh` is called, and accepts any arguments.

```
$ComputerName = 'RemotePCName'
$MyData1 = 'ArbitraryData1'
$MyData2 = 'ArbitraryData2'
$Temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ArgumentList $MyData1, $MyData2 -ScriptBlock {
    if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7) {
        return "[$($Env:ComputerName)] {$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)} ($($args[0]), $($args[1]))"
    }
    else {
        return (C:\Users\Public\PSv7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock -args $args)
    }
}
Write-Host "$Temp"
```

**Defined Parameter Version:**

This version is the similar to the above basic parameter version, except the parameters are explicitly defined.

```
$ComputerName = 'RemotePCName'
$MyData1 = 'ArbitraryData1'
$MyData2 = 'ArbitraryData2'
$Temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ArgumentList $MyData1, $MyData2 -ScriptBlock {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Param1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Param2
    )
    if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7) {
        return "[$($Env:ComputerName)] {$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)} ($Param1, $Param2)"
    }
    else {
        return (C:\Users\Public\PSv7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock -args $Param1, $Param2)
    }
}
Write-Host "$Temp"
```

**Update:**

Interesting! At the time of creating the above examples I was largely throwing things at the wall and seeing what sticks.  But, when looking into [-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.2#-command---c), in it I found the following interesting statements:

> The Command parameter only accepts a script block for execution when
> it can recognize the value passed to Command as a ScriptBlock type.
> This is only possible when running pwsh from another PowerShell host.

and:

> When called from within an existing PowerShell session, the results
> are returned to the parent shell as deserialized XML objects, not live
> objects.

Haven't done any experiments yet, but this gives me hope that complex objects can be returned from a call to pwsh.exe.

**Updated Alternative Version:**

Having given some thought to how the above examples work, I realized that a script block can contain another script block. So, in this example the outer script block is ran on the remote system, and the inner script block, without any concern for what version it is currently running in, is passed to pwsh.exe.  A hash table is created, returned, saved to `$Temp`, and then `Format-Table` is used to show its content.  This means that complex objects can be returned to the calling script.

As with the very first example, this code assumes the PowerShell Zip package is copied to the PSv7 in the Public user profile, but if version 7 is installed, then can probably be reduced to `pwsh`.

```
$ComputerName = 'RemotePCName'
$MyData1 = 'ArbitraryData1'
$MyData2 = 'ArbitraryData2'

$Temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ArgumentList $MyData1, $MyData2 -ScriptBlock {
    return C:\Users\Public\PSv7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -args $args {
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
            [string]$Param1,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
            [string]$Param2
        )
        return @{
            ComputerName = $Env:ComputerName
            PSVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
            Param1 = $Param1
            Param2 = $Param2
        }
    }
}
$Temp | Format-Table
```

Comment: Invoking debug data as a command, holy! Encountered a problem though, I am unable to pass params through $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock, any way to do this?

Comment: Okay, I needed to pass -args instead of -ArgumentList after $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock. Works like a charm now! 
Weird though how Powershell doesn't have an easy built in way to change the version, like have parameter -PSVersion when setting up a session or invoking a command. Microsoft is pushing the standard to not update the already installed Powershell, but instead install a new installation of Powershell.

Comment: @Shrimpis, glad this works for you.  Based on your comments, and figuring multiple people may find this useful, I decided to add 2 more versions that accept parameters.