# Powershell, remote machine initiates file transfer

Tags: powershell, file-transfer

Is it possible to script connecting to a remote machine, and having that remote machine initiate a file transfer from a NFS share?
Goal is that I want to eliminate the machine I'm on as a middle man.  all the examples I've used or come across facilitate the transfer. But if I'm on VPN or somewhere with limited bandwidth, I want the machines to talk to each other, not through my laptop.  Updates range from 300MB to 1.5GB.
Not a huge issue when I'm remoting in to the machine stuff is being copied from, but I want to update my script to put the burden on the remote machine to initiate the file transfer.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You can have two scripts, each on a different computer, communicate with each other (for example, finding each other by IP and using TCP), or you can have a script execute a script block on a remote computer.  The problem with executing a script block on the remote system is that you have to have the correct services running on the remote system and possibly some permissions opened up (Been a while, so don't remember exact details). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494335/4190564) that starts 5.1, but then switches to 7.x on the remote system.

Comment: [Running Remote Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-5.1)  has these [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-5.1).  For TCP, search for code examples with TcpClient and TcpListener .

Comment: Yes.   Your server would be a two port application.  Port 1 is a server to your client. Port 2 is a client to machines where data is transferred.  Usually this type server application is called a relay.